# PHPMailer- Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to use the phpmailer in my project, but the SMTP settings for gmail doesn't seem to be right. I referred a few questions asked here before, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

```
<?php
    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();                                
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                   
    $mail->Port = 587;                          
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                       
    $mail->Username = '';  //gmail address                
    $mail->Password = ''; // gmail password
    $mail->From = 'user@domain.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'John Doe';
    $mail->AddAddress('yadayada@gmail.com', 'Nick');  // Add a recipient
    $mail->IsHTML(true);                             // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'message body';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    $mail->addAttachment('images/apache_pb.png');
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: is this hosted on godaddy ?

Comment: PHPMailer- Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: No. I'm currently doing it on localhost

Comment: Is setting From directly legal ?  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: If there is a firewall enabled, have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: should it be enabled or disabled?

Comment: Try disabling first, if its enabled then it will need a rule to open the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to have installed php_openssl.dll, if you use wampserver it's pretty easy, search and apply the extension for PHP.

In the example change this:

```
   //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission 465 ssl
    $mail->Port = 465;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

and then you recived an email from gmail talking about to enable the option to Less Safe Access Applications here https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Thanks a lot man. It worked. But will this work on live servers like Godaddy or amazon?

Comment: Ookey.. Thank you :)

Comment: This advice is incorrect. You need the openssl extension to do either TLS or SSL, so enabling that ext will work without changing your code. No it won't work on GoDaddy, because they block all external SMTP. You do not need to enable less secure apps. All of this is explained in detail in the guide that the error linked to, so you could have avoided wasting many people's time.

Comment: No you can discuss with godaddy support and open firewall port. other way is you can use google MX record in domain setting to connect with gmail.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$mail->Host = 'mail.servce.com';
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting a piece of code without any text is often not very helpful.